Move row to another sheet when box is checked not working but other text in script working
I want to run two bits of script on my seets. It seems once I fix one thing, another part that was working breaks!
Function 1 - script to move a whole row from one "Open" sheet (tab) to another "Closed" sheet (tab) upon a check box tick is not working, neither is moving a row from "Closed" sheet back to "Open" when the box is unchecked.
Function 2 - Script to enter the current date in a column cell when that row is edited. The date function works, when I edit a row it puts in the current date however when i try to delete the date it keeps putting it back in
I can't see where i'm going wrong here and if anyone can help I would really apprechiate it!
Script Below
    function onEdit(){
    var mainSheet = "Open"
    var sheetToMoveTheRow = "Closed"

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getActiveRange();

    if(sheet.getName() == "Open" && range.getColumn() == 11 && range.getValue() == true) {
      var row = range.getRow();
      var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Closed");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1);
      sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      sheet.deleteRow(row);
    } else if(sheet.getName() == "Closed" && range.getColumn() == 11 && range.getValue() == false) {
     var row = range.getRow();
     var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
     var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Open");
     const aVals = targetSheet.getRange(1,1,targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1).getValues();
     const targetRow = aVals.filter(String).length + 1;
     var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetRow , 1);
     sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
     sheet.deleteRow(row);
    }
    }

    function onEdit(e) {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
      var column = range.getColumn();
      var row = range.getRow();

      if (column >= 5 && column <= 9) {
        var currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'dd-MM-yyyy');
        sheet.getRange(row, 5).setValue(currentDate); // Set the date in column E
        console.log('Date set in column E for row', row, ':', currentDate);
 }
}

As mentioned above, everytime i've fixed one part, another breaks. At the point where i do not know where I am going wrong and don't know where else to look.
